# How can I reuse my objects instead of destroying them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi guys I just started with unity, c # ... I created a script that should make a writing appear and disappear ... the problem is that once the writing appears, then it never reappears since I destroy the object " gameObject "and therefore can no longer be recreated ... How can I fix the code ??

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class Com : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject uiObject ; 

  void Start(){

         uiObject.SetActive(false);
         

  }

  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider player)
  {
     
 
      if(player.gameObject.tag=="Player"){

        uiObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine("WaitForSec");

      }
  }
  IEnumerator WaitForSec(){

yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
 Destroy(uiObject);
 Destroy(gameObject);

  }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with not using `uiObject.SetActive(false)` instead of destroying it?

Comment: Above comment is probably what you're looking for, but just in case, you can also look into [`Object Pooling`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand first what is Object pooling, which is making a pool of object that are stored in memory, and then you access them when need one, this will save the hiccup of creating a new instance.

With regard to your code, to reuse the same game object again, you do not need to destroy it, destroy method means it will remove the object from memory. what you need to do is to use gameobject.SetActive(false);

when you need to reuse the same gameobject again, just use gameObject.SetActive(true);

Keep in mind you may need to reset some of its properties like its rotation or position OnEnable